# django - ajax - call python function from jquery/ajax

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, ajax

I'm working with Django to create a small website. in this project, I have some DateTime fields.
I would use ajax (via another button) to set up the UTC date keeping in mind the solar time and daylight saving time.
I created a python function which computes the hour shift. I would recall that function in the ajax code. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You have not added full code. in django you can if the request is ajax or not with this method `is_ajax`

You can send payload as json and grab it from `request`

```
def example_ajax(request):
   if request.is_ajax():
       # some thing here
   return JsonResponse(A DICT GOES GOEST THERE)
```